# Query histogram prometheus metric from New Relic

Tags: prometheus, newrelic

We have a service that uses a prometheus histogram to record the time an event takes to complete.

We are sending this histogram metric to Prometheus and from Prometheus to New Relic too and we want to show the average time this event takes over the time.

In Prometheus we use the following to calculate the average over the time
`rate(event_duration_seconds_sum[5m])/rate(event_duration_seconds_count[5m])`

When we query the service metrics endpoint we can see the value of `event_duration_seconds_sum` is increasing over the time.

In new Relic, when we select the `event_duration_seconds_sum` from `Metrics` we were expecting to have the value increasing over the time but what we see is a metric value of type `{"type":"summary","count":1,"sum":126.0,"min":null,"max":null}` and the sum value goes up and down over the time.

We would like to get the average of the metric over the time in New Relic too and as New Relic accept PromQL queries we are thinking to use the same formula as we use from Prometheus.

By the way,  the different values we have for `event_duration_seconds_sum` in New Relic is making us doubt if we can use the same approach as we used for Prometheus.

Anyone already face the same situation?